# Java to Excel 2010

Tags: java, excel

I have a piece of code which is creating an Excel file by using an open source library named OpenXLS-6.0.6.
My pc has Windows XP Professional and Office 2003.
However I have notice that since I have migrated to Windows 7 and Office 2010, I am not able to open the generated Excel file anymore.
I went to the OpenXLS website and indeed is specified that: "Compatible with Excel '97-2003 (.xls) file formats "

Is anybody aware of a library that is able to generate Excel files compatible with Office 2010?
I had a quick check on ExcelAPI and POI, but it is mentioned that they deal with Excel up to the Office 2003 version(at least this was my understanding).

Comment: should this library be in Java?

Answer (score 3):

There is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). It is not the easiest library to use, but creating Excel files is the easiest thing that you can do with it. [How to.](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf), [How to](http://sanjaal.com/java/105/java-file/writing-to-excel-file-using-apache-poi/) 2. I have also seen  commercial libraries that have free versions too.

> XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007
>   OOXML (.xlsx) file format.

Xlsx is also used in Office 2010.

Answer (score 0):

.xlsx are a simple zip package that contains some simple .xml file , so unzip it and do what you want to do with data.

read more documents about openxml and MS office in microsoft web site.